# The input of the op-amp (DC power supply & function generator)

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, function-generator

What is the difference between a  DC power supply (PS) and a function grnerator(FG) as an input of an op-amp?

While trying to test my summing amplifier circuit, I figured out that the op-amp do not work when the PS is the input of the op-amp.

This is the part of whole circuit:

[image]

[image]

When I set the PS output to 1V in constant voltage mode and connected it to the inverting input of the op-amp, I expected the output of the op-amp to be 1V as same as 1V.

Also I expected that the voltage at the inverting input to be 0 because it is virtual ground.

However, when I did that, the voltage at the inverting input was more than 0V and PS was operated in constant current mode with a few amperes.

On the other hand, this circuit operates well when I connect FG to the input of the op-amp.

What is the problem when connecting the PS output to op-amp input?

---

To help you understand the circumstances, I will explain my entire circuit below.

This is the full sketch of my circuit

[image]

I supply the power to two op-amps(TL082) from DC power supply(Vcc+ and Vcc-).

Vcc+ is also connected to the input of voltage reference (MAX6250).

The output of voltage reference is 5V and it is modulated from 0V to 5V by resistors and potentiometers.

*V_dither* is connected to function generator which have 10Vpp amplitude with 100Hz freq.

*Verr* is the final output of this summing amplifier circuit which is sum of the modulated voltage, *V_dither* and *Vlia_in*

*Vlia_in* is the place where unexpected situation occurs.

I connected the another power supply to *Vlia_in* and found out that situation I described above happens.(nonzero voltage at virtual ground, large amount of current(a few amperes))

Comment: You are connecting something wrong, but due to lack of details what you connected where and how, it is impossible to know what the problem is.

Comment: @Justme I've made up for a lack of explanation. I hope it helps you to understand the circumstances.

Comment: not really, because you are not telling how exactly you are connecting the positive and negative and ground wires of the power supplies, and whether the power supplies are both referenced to ground or to each other or completely floating. The function generator ground is usually referenced to mains earth, so it is possible you are short circuiting the supply via mains earth.

Comment: @Justme Every ground in PCB is connected to PCB cooper ground plane which is referenced to the ground terminal of the power supplies.  And I am not sure whether the power supplies are referenced to the earth ground. So, I guess you mean that I need to PCB ground plane be referenced to floating ground.